# NodeJs TimeStamp not setting up in correct format Firebase-Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, serverside-javascript

I'm not getting the correct timestamp format for the firestore. From Nodejs I've Also tried a lot of others StackOverflow answers but it doesn't work at all.

The Way I'm using is here:

```
const Timestamp = require("firebase-firestore-timestamp");
let timeStamp = Timestamp.now();
```

The *result* on Firestore:

[image]

What I **expect** the *result* is:

[image]

The Way I'm Using:

NodeEngine=>

```
"engines": {
"node": "12.16.1"
 },
```

db module=>

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
const config = require("./config");

const db = firebase.initializeApp(config.firebaseConfig);

module.exports = db;
```

my config files =>

```
'use strict';
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const assert = require('assert');

dotenv.config();

const {
    PORT,
    HOST,
    HOST_URL,
    API_KEY,
    AUTH_DOMAIN,
    DATABASE_URL,
    PROJECT_ID,
    STORAGE_BUCKET,
    MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    APP_ID
} = process.env;

assert(PORT, 'PORT is required');
assert(HOST, 'HOST is required');

module.exports = {
    port: PORT,
    host: HOST,
    url: HOST_URL,
    firebaseConfig: {
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        authDomain: AUTH_DOMAIN,
        databaseURL: DATABASE_URL,
        projectId: PROJECT_ID,
        storageBucket: STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: APP_ID
    }
}
```

controller to setup the data=>

```
const firebase = require("../db");
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

for setting data:
await firestore
      .collection("alpha")
      .doc("beta")
      .set(data);
```

here data means a data object along with other parameters

the *data*:

```
{
 
  level: 2,
  endTime: { seconds: 1648387945, nanoseconds: 437000000 },
  nextLevel:12
}
```

depencencies =>

```
 "dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"firebase": "^8.0.1",}
```

Comment: Why do you have that third party package? You can create Firestore timestamp directly using Firebase SDK. Can you share the code that you are using to add document in Firestore?

Comment: @Dharmaraj 

`db module=> 
const firebase = require("firebase");
const config = require("./config");

const db = firebase.initializeApp(config.firebaseConfig);

module.exports = db;



controller to setup the data=>
const firebase = require("../db");
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

for setting data:
await firestore
      .collection("alpha")
      .doc("beta")
      .set(data);`

i'm not using the firebase-admin sdk but the simple firebase sdk

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code? It'll be much more readable. Also where the `data` that is being passed in `set()` coming from? Please add that as well.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've changed it

Comment: Can you try using Firebase SDK directly as in my answer instead of that npm package?

Comment: Does Firebase SDK directly mean using the firebase-admin? right?

Comment: Yes. `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` works as well. I saw `require("firebase");` in your code so I thought you are using FIrebase client SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Timestamp to a document without using any third party packages as shown below:

```
const data = {
  endTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  // also add other fields
}


await firebase.firestore()
  .collection("alpha")
  .doc("beta")
  .set(data);
```

Comment: i'm getting this:

`endTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'serverTimestamp' of undefined`

Comment: @Ammar can you edit your question and add completed code. It's hard to understand how you've imported firebase in that file. Also what is your Firebase version?

Comment: I've update it, should need more to explain?

Comment: @Ammar FieldValue should be defined. What is your Firebase version? Also it might be best to post your code to add document as a single code snippet including the imports. Currently it's all in different snippets so its harder to understand. Like you have hard coded seconds field in there.

Comment: I'm not using the firebase-cli (as currently, I don't need to use the functions of firebase)
but the dependencies I'm using are Below:

 "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^8.0.1",}

Comment: @Ammar I am not referring to the CLI. It'll be best if you could post your code file as a single snippet as you have. The "controller to setup the data" code .file